How can we efficiently determine in a table with items whether the orders contain only our products / third party or mixed?
I have a dataset in Python, in which we have OrderNumbers, IsOurs, whether a product is ours or not and we have the amount that the product costs. We would like to classify every order, whether it only contains our product, whether it contains a mix of products or only contains products from others. We can generate the dataset as follows:
# Number of orders and products
num_orders = 1000
max_products_per_order = 10

# Generate random OrderNumbers
order_numbers = np.repeat(np.arange(1, num_orders + 1), np.random.randint(1, max_products_per_order + 1, num_orders))

# Generate IsOurs column with random True/False values
is_ours = np.random.choice([True, False], size=len(order_numbers))

# Generate unique ProductID
product_ids = np.arange(1, len(order_numbers) + 1)

# Generate random amounts for each product
np.random.seed(42)  # Set seed for reproducibility
amounts = np.round(np.random.uniform(10, 500, size=len(order_numbers)), 2)

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'OrderNumber': order_numbers,
    'ProductID': product_ids,
    'IsOurs': is_ours,
    'Amount': amounts
})

Now, in order to calculate that, we can do the following:
First solution
df['OnlyOurs'] = df.groupby(['OrderNumber'])['IsOurs'].transform('all')
df['Mixed'] = df.groupby(['OrderNumber'])['IsOurs'].transform('any')
df['Mixed'] = df.Mixed & (df.OnlyOurs == False)
df['OnlyOther'] = (df.Mixed == False) & (df.OnlyOurs == False)
df['MixClass'] = "Mix"
df.loc[df['OnlyOther'], 'MixClass'] = "Other"
df.loc[df['OnlyOurs'], 'MixClass'] = "Ours"
df.groupby('MixClass')['Amount'].sum()

On my computer this runs in about 40ms, quite fast.
If we were to write it a bit more elegant, which is:
Second solution
df['MixClass'] = df.groupby('OrderNumber')['IsOurs'].transform(
    lambda x: 'Ours' if x.all() else 'Other' if not x.any() else 'Mix')

This runs significantly slower. I was wondering whether I am missing something on how I can improve the performance of the one liner. I am aware that this is because in the first solution I use vectorised functions, in the second I don't but define a function of my own. However, I was wondering whether a more elegant approach exists, without that much of "boilerplate" code.

it is a trade off ; I do not think you can use a one liner for your use case without losing performance

You can use np.select:
g = df.groupby('OrderNumber')['IsOurs']
condlist = [g.transform(f) for f in ['all', 'any']]
choicelist = ['Ours', 'Mix']
df['MixClass'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='Other')

Timings:
%timeit first_solution(df.copy())
%timeit second_solution(df.copy())
%timeit np_select(df.copy())

2.08 ms ± 590 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
84.7 ms ± 22.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
913 µs ± 31.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# `first_solution` here already adjusted with 
# `g = df.groupby('OrderNumber')['IsOurs']` to gain a little more speed

Equality check:
df_second.equals(df_np_select)
# True

You can put this in a one-liner, of course:
df['MixClass'] = np.select([df.groupby('OrderNumber')['IsOurs'].transform(f) for f in ['all', 'any']], ['Ours', 'Mix'], default='Other')

I would not personally call doing so 'more elegant'. The most important thing is that people can easily understand what the code does.

If you are looking for a fast solution for very large dataframes (i.e., for instance
num_orders = 100000 and
max_products_per_order = 1000),
you might use duckdb:
import duckdb # pip install duckdb

con = duckdb.connect()
con.register("df", df)

query = """
SELECT 
    OrderNumber,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(CAST(IsOurs AS INT)) = COUNT(IsOurs) THEN 'Ours'
        WHEN SUM(CAST(IsOurs AS INT)) = 0 THEN 'Other'
        ELSE 'Mix'
    END AS MixClass
FROM df
GROUP BY OrderNumber
"""

pd.merge(df, con.execute(query).df(), on='OrderNumber', how='left')

con.close()

